# In a fragment shader, why can't I use a flat input integer to index a uniform array of sampler2D?

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader, textures, glsles

I want to specify textures to be used when I render an array of sprites. So I put a texture index in their vertex data, and pass it as a flat value from my vertex shader to my fragment shader, but can't use it to index an array of samplers as expected because compiler sees it as "non-constant". Instead I have to resort to the disgusting code below. Can anyone explain what is going on here?

```
const int numTextures = 2;

uniform sampler2D textures[numTextures];

in vec2 uv;
flat in int tex;
out vec4 colour;

void main(void)
{
    // this caused the compiler error 
        /// "sampler arrays indexed with non-constant expressions"
    // colour = texture( textures[ tex ], uv );

    // hence this (ugh) ...
    switch ( tex ) 
    {
        case 0:
            colour = texture( textures[0], uv );
            break;
        case 1:
            colour = texture( textures[1], uv );
            break;
        default:
            colour = vec4( 0.3f, 0.3f, 0.3f, 1.0f );
            break;
    };
}
```

Comment: Would it be possible to use `sampler2DArray`? See [Sampler](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Sampler_(GLSL))

Comment: using the mipmaps is a cool idea. I think for this applcation I will use large texture pages, maintain separate draw lists for each and switch the active texture inbetwween the draw element calls in my render  func.

Answer (score 8):

> [...] but can't use it to index an array of samplers as expected because compiler sees it as "non-constant" [...]

In GLSL up to version 3.30 respectively GLSL ES up to version 3.00, the index of an array of texture samplers has to be a constant expression:

[GLSL 3.30 Specification - 4.1.7 Samplers (page 21)](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/GLSLangSpec.3.30.pdf)
[GLSL ES 3.00 Specification - 4.1.7.1 Samplers (page 29)](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/es/3.0/GLSL_ES_Specification_3.00.pdf):

> Samplers aggregated into arrays within a shader (using square brackets [ ]) can only be indexed with integral constant expressions [...]

---

In later version, the index to an array of samplers has to be "dynamically uniform". This means the index has to be the "same" for all fragments (e.g. a constant or a uniform variable).

[GLSL 4.60 Specification - 4.1.11. Opaque Types (page 31)](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/GLSLangSpec.4.60.pdf)
[GLSL ES 3.20 Specification - 4.1.11. Opaque Types (page 32)](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/es/3.2/GLSL_ES_Specification_3.20.pdf)

> When aggregated into arrays within a shader, opaque types can only be indexed with a dynamically uniform integral expression. [...]
>
> [...] Sampler types (e.g. **sampler2D**) are opaque types [...]

[GLSL 4.60 Specification - 3.8.2. Dynamically Uniform Expressions (page 20)](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/GLSLangSpec.4.60.pdf)
[GLSL ES 3.20 Specification - 3.9.3. Dynamically Uniform Expressions (page 22)](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/es/3.2/GLSL_ES_Specification_3.20.pdf)

> A fragment-shader expression is dynamically uniform if all fragments evaluating it get the same resulting value.

---

A `flat` fragment shader input  is invariant for a single primitive, but not for the entire mesh, not for all the primitives which are processed by a single "draw call" respectively it is not the same for an invocation group. A (`flat`) fragment shader input is not [Dynamically uniform](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Core_Language_(GLSL)#Dynamically_uniform_expression).

Comment: thank  you for such a detailed replay. I see that in the newer versions of GLSL I can do what I want. I should probably upgrade my laptop which has an un-upgradeable gpu supporting only GLSL 130.

Comment: @MarkL No, the index of an array of samplers can never depend on a varying (`in`) variable.

Comment: yes, that makes sense, but I'm using a flat int, which is invariant.

Comment: @MarkL No, it is invariant for a single primitive, but not for the entire mesh, not for all the primitives wich are processed by a single "draw call" respectively it is not the same for an invocation group.

Comment: OK I get it now .. I had assumed that the shaders were executed per primitive. Obvious nonsense now I come to think about it! Thanks for helping me out with this one.