# Arrays in uniform blocks cannot be indexed with vertex attributes, right?

Tags: opengl, graphics, glsl

I was wondering if I can index into a uniform buffer array with a value contained in the vertices I draw, like:

```
layout (location = 0) in vec3 position;
layout (location = 1) in flat int idx;

layout(binding = 0, std140) uniform uniformValues
    {
        float values[100];
};

void main() 
{
     values[idx];
}
```

My understanding is that this is not possible because

```
'in flat int idx'
```

Is most likely not a 'dynamically uniform expression', and according to the documentation cannot be used to index into a uniform buffer array:

> There are places where GLSL requires the expression to be dynamically
> uniform. All of the following must use a dynamically uniform
> expression:
>
> ```
> -The index to buffer-backed interface block arrays.
> ```

However I came across information from the [same source](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Bindless_Texture) regarding how to access an array of samplers holding texture handles for 'bindless textures', and it says (emphasis mine):

> Sampler and image types used in default block uniform variables can be
> populated from handles rather than the index of a binding point.
> **These types can also now be passed as Shader Stage inputs/outputs (using the flat interpolation qualifier where needed).** **They can be
> used as Vertex Attributes,** where they are treated as 64-bit integers
> on the OpenGL side. And they **can be used in Interface Blocks of all
> kinds**; buffer-backed interface blocks treat them as 64-bit integers.

It's saying, I believe, that instead of doing this:

```
layout (location = 0) in flat int textureBinding;

layout (binding = 0) uniform sampler2D textures[16];

void main()
{
     textures[textureBinding];
}
```

You do this:

```
layout (location = 0) in flat int bindlessTextureHandle;

layout (binding = 0) uniform textureBuffer 
{
      sampler2D textures[200];
}

void main()
{
     textures[bindlessTextureHandle];
}
```

'bindlessTextureHandle' isn't a 'dynamically uniform expression', how can it be used to index into uniform buffer?

All of the following must use a dynamically uniformexpression:

> ```
> -The index to buffer-backed interface block arrays.
> ```

So why is it saying that you can index into 'interface blocks' of all kinds with values from vertex inputs?

Also are you allowed to index into:

```
'uniform sampler2D[16] textures;'
```

with a 'non-dynamically uniform expression'?

Comment: *"Also are you allowed to index into `uniform sampler2D[16] textures;` with a 'non-dynamically uniform expression'?"* No. See [In a fragment shader, why can't I use a flat input integer to index a uniform array of sampler2D?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54388274/in-a-fragment-shader-why-cant-i-use-a-flat-input-integer-to-index-a-uniform-ar/54388460#54388460)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My understanding is that this is not possible because
>
> ```
> in flat int idx
> ```
>
> Is most likely not a 'dynamically uniform expression', and according
> to the documentation cannot be used to index into a uniform buffer
> array.

You are right that you need a dynamically uniform value to index into an uniform buffer array. However, this:

> ```
> layout(binding = 0, std140) uniform uniformValues
> {
>         float values[100];
> };
> ```

is **not** a uniform buffer array. That is an array inside a single uniform buffer object, and you can index with non-uniform values into this array as you like. A uniform buffer array would be:

```
 layout(binding = 0, std140) uniform myUBO
 {
         float value;
 } myUBOArray[4];
```

The rest of your question gets even more obscure. You sometimes reference "The index to buffer-backed interface block arrays", which your code never uses. This is talking about SSBOs, which use interface blocks of the form `layout(...) buffer foo {...}`.

> So why is it saying that you can index into 'interface blocks' of all kinds with values from vertex inputs?

Because that is how it is. You just need to understand that indexing into an array of interface blocks is not the same as indexing some other array (which might or might not be defined inside an interface block, doesn't matter).

> Also are you allowed to index into:
>
> ```
> uniform sampler2D[16] textures; with a 'non-dynamically uniform expression'?
> ```

No, not in standard GL.

The first thing about **bindless textures** is that this is **not** a core feature of any OpenGL version released to date (which is 4.6 at the time of writing this).It is only defined as an *extension* [`GL_ARB_bindless_textures`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/extensions/ARB/ARB_bindless_texture.txt) which some modern GPUs and drivers expose, but the availability of that feature is quite far from being universal.

Second, the extension spec above explains: "Sampler and image handles passed to texture built-in functions must be  dynamically uniform", so it still doesn't get you there. However, the extension [`GL_NV_gpu_shader5`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/extensions/NV/NV_gpu_shader5.txt) removes that restriction. So on recent *NVIDIA* GPUs, you can get a non-dymically uniform index into an array of bindless texture samplers - but performance will still suffer by a significant amount if you do so.

Comment: So non-dynamically uniform index can be used to index uniform block { float[100];] but not uniform block { sampler2D[100]; } . Both are uniform buffer blocks, right?

Comment: Partly. `sampler` types are not even _allowed_ inside uniform blocks in unextended GL (only bindless textures would allow such a thing). The spec clearly states that for samplers aggeragted into arrays, you need a dynamically uniform index, otherwise the results are undefined. Not sure why you so desperately seem to try to mix different things up. THere are a couple of things for which the spec mandates dynamically uniform expressions, and indexing interface block arrays as well as indexing sampler arrays are both two such things, but apart from that, they have nothing in common.

Comment: If these 64 bit texture integer handles can't be used to index texture sampler arrays, what good is passing them in through vertex attributes? That page says "These types can also now be passed as Shader Stage inputs/outputs" - "They can be used as Vertex Attributes". Being non-dynamically uniform values, you can access arrays, just not what they're intended for, which is textures, right? How could you use them?

Comment: To quote from the `GL_ARB_bindless_textures` extension: "This extension allows OpenGL applications to access texture objects in shaders without first binding each texture to one of a limited number of texture image units. [...] these extensions significantly reduce the amount of API and internal GL driver overhead needed to manage resource bindings." This is what bindless textures is about: not having to _bind_ a small subset of textures for each draw call. It is not about non-uniform access to textures at all. As I said, only in combination with `GL_NV_gpu_shader5` you get that capability.

Comment: I also see high chances that this is just an XY problem. You have never specified what exactly you really want to do. You can get alot done with standard texture arrays (not arrays of sampler objects) already.

Comment: I'm trying to understand how these texture handles can be used, for example, embedding the texture I want to use within the vertex itself, which doesn't look possible. As I understand it you can only access textures in the shader with texture handles with dynamically uniform indexes, such as gl_drawId in a multidraw command. If texture handles can only be used where dynamically uniform indexes are required, then what use is it having these texture handles passed in as vertex attributes? That's what I don't understand.

Comment: These handles are there to reference indivudual textures. Without bindlesss textures, you can't directly reference textures from a shader, you only reference texture units.

Comment: But you can't use them to reference any textures if they're passed in as vertex attributes, right?

Comment: Within the guarantees of the ARB extension, you can reference them with dynamically uniform expressions, no matter if they come from vertex attributes or elsewhere. Now specifying dynamically uniform vertex attributes might be pointless in most cases (but not all), but that doesn't really matter. The feature is called "bindless textures", not "nun-uniform texture access", and with the concept of addressing textures with 64bit IDs automatically comes the ability to specify these values as vertex attributes, but that is not the point why they are there.

Comment: I see, so that part of the docs is just saying that these texture handles CAN be passed in as vertex attributes, even though in order to use them every single vertex would have to have the same texture handle value within that shader invocation, as I understand it. Edit: wait, but you don't index the sampler array with the handles themselves, you populate the sampler array with the handles, and index into that... Oh.... this is confusing. I think I'll leave it at that for now. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, unless you are on nvidia which implements other extensions which remove the dynaimcally uniform restriction.

Comment: "Edit: wait, but you don't index the sampler array with the handles themselves, you populate the sampler array with the handles, and index into that... " That doesn't make a difference, it does matter what value the individual sampler has (across multiple invocations in an invocation group) when you do the `texture` call. If that value is not dynamically uniform because it comes directly from a vertex attribute, or if this value is not dynamically unifrom because you got it by indexing with a vertex attribute into an uniform array of values does not make the slightest difference.

Answer (score 1):

There are a myriad of separate, overlapping issues here.

Indexing an array *within* a uniform block has never been limited to dynamically uniform expressions (generally, see below). Even in GL 3.x, you can index an array within a buffer-backed block with an arbitrary index.

However, you're not asking about a general array; you're asking about arrays of textures. Or to be more general, the entire sequence of operations leading to the computation of a sampler type through bindless textures.

That entire sequence *must* be dynamically uniform (unless you're on NVIDIA, which allows arbitrary expressions). It doesn't matter if you're indexing an SSBO array, using an input variable to pass a texture handle directly, or anything else. The value that leads to the acquisition of a sampler type *must* be dynamically uniform.

> So why is it saying that you can index into 'interface blocks' of all kinds with values from vertex inputs?

Because you can.

A common misunderstanding of what "dynamically uniform" means is that it is a static property. That an expression *by itself* is either dynamically uniform or not. This is close to true, but it's not actually true.

Some expressions are dynamically uniform by their nature. You could call these "statically dynamically uniform" expressions. A constant expression is always dynamically uniform, for example.

However, being dynamically uniform is about the *value* of the expression. All invocations (within the rendering command) must result in the same *value*. An `in` variable for a shader stage can be dynamically uniform so long as it just so happens to always have the same value within the rendering command. For example, a VS could access a value from a `uniform` array using `gl_DrawID` (which is dynamically uniform), pass that as an `in` to the FS, and the FS can use that value as a sampler. Or to access an array of samplers. Or whatever. All FS invocations will get the same value within the draw command, so that value is dynamically uniform.

Comment: Is requiring sampler arrays to be indexed by dynamically uniform indexes a limitation of OpenGL or of graphics cards? I was reading that in Vulkan the flag (something like samplerNonDynamicallyUniformIndexable) is true on most platforms.