# Why is my array of sampler2D always using texture unit 0?

Tags: arrays, opengl, textures, uniform

#### Texture header

```
class texture
{
public:
    texture(int tex_unit, const std::string& filename);

    GLuint get_texture() { return tex; }
    GLint get_tex_unit() { return unit; }
    std::string get_filename() { return filename; }

private:
    GLuint tex;
    GLint unit; 
    std::string filename;
};
```

#### Texture source

```
texture::texture(int _unit, const std::string& _filename)
    : unit(_unit)
    , filename(_filename)
{
    int width, height, channels;
    uint8_t* data = stbi_load(filename.c_str(), &width, &height, &channels, 3);
    if (!data)
        throw std::runtime_error("texture: " + std::string(stbi_failure_reason()));

    glGenTextures(1, &tex);
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0 + unit);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, width, height, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);

    stbi_image_free(data);
}
```

Two textures are created with texture::unit set to 0 and 1.

```
scene_textures["background"] = std::make_shared<texture>(0, "data/milkyway.bmp");
scene_textures["earth"] = std::make_shared<texture>(1, "data/earth.bmp");
```

Then before I run the (compute) shader, I bind the textures to the right texture units (simplified for clarity).

```
auto background = scene_textures["background"];
auto earth = scene_textures["earth"];

glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, background->get_texture());
glUniform1i(rt_shader->get_uniform("textures[0]"), 0);

glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0 + 1);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, scene_textures["earth"]->get_texture());
glUniform1i(rt_shader->get_uniform("textures[1]"), 1);
```

In the shader there's an array of 8 sampler2D and I use the texture function to lookup the texels, e.g.

```
uniform sampler2D textures[8];
texture(textures[0], uv)
texture(textures[1], uv)
```

The problem is the shader always uses texture unit 0 (background texture) whether I use textures[0] or textures[1]. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here. I would try to use sampler2DArray but I'd like to know what the problem is here first.

update:
To index the sample2D array I use a variable stored in an SSBO (scene_objects.mat.texture). The rest of the shader code which accesses scene_objects works as expected.

```
struct physics
{
    float attraction;
};

struct material
{
    float diffuse_color[3];
    float specular_exponent;
    int texture;
};

struct scene_object
{
    int type;
    float position[3];

    // sphere
    float radius;

    material mat;
    physics phys;
};

layout (std430, binding = 1) buffer scene_objects
{
    int obj_cnt;
    scene_object objects[];
};
```

Comment: Do you use the constant index (`textures[1]`) or do you use an input variable (`textures[index]`)? See [In a fragment shader, why can't I use a flat input integer to index a uniform array of sampler2D?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54388274/in-a-fragment-shader-why-cant-i-use-a-flat-input-integer-to-index-a-uniform-ar/54388460#54388460)

Comment: I use a variable stored in a struct in an SSBO. `texture(textures[obj.mat.texture], uv)`. Just to be sure that `obj.mat.texture` is set to 1 like it should be there, I wrote `if (obj.mat.texture != 1)` then output an obvious colour and return if it's not 1. The code isn't executed so it looks like `obj.mat.texture` holds the correct value.

Comment: What is the data structure of the SSBO?

Comment: I've updated the question with the SSBO structure.

Comment: Silly question: Has the shader program been installed (`glUseProgram`), before you set the uniform (`glUniform1i`)?

Comment: Yes. Right before the call to `glUniform1i` I call `rt_shader->use()` which calls `glUseProgram(pro_id);`.